# Group returned result by mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

```
table x

labref   name  repeat_status
111      L          1
111      L          1
111      K          1
111      K          1
111      L          2
111      L          2
111      M          1
111      M          1
```

The result that i need is

```
labref   name  repeat_status
111      L          1
111      L          2
111      K          1
111      M          1
```

I have tried this query but it does not bring the result, needs tweaking

```
SELECT name, repeat_status
FROM `x`
WHERE labref = '111'
GROUP BY repeat_status;
```

suggestions!

Comment: have you tried using 'distinct' at the start of your select statement?

Comment: `GROUP BY name, repeat_status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     SELECT name, repeat_status
     FROM `x`
     WHERE labref = '111'
     GROUP BY name ,repeat_status;
```

Comment: First of all the answer which is mentioned requires 3 columns, not 2. Then, you don't need group by here but distinct.

Answer (score 1):

```
 select DISTINCT labref ,name, repeat_status
 FROM x
 WHERE labref = '111'
```

This query would get the result you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  labref,name,repeat_status
FROM `x`
WHERE labref = '111'
GROUP BY name,repeat_status;
```

Comment: Do you know what group by is doing here?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, repeat_status
FROM `x`
WHERE labref = '111'
GROUP BY name,repeat_status;
```